# Make Array of Widgets in GWT

Tags: gwt, nullpointerexception, widget

I am trying to implement array of Horizontal panels in GWT as follows:

```
HorizontalPanel[] hp = new HorizontalPanel[5];
VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();

for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
      hp[i].add(new Label("hello"));
      vp.add(hp[i]);
}
```

but it gives NullPointerException in 1st line of loop .

Where am i wrong ?
How to implement this in GWT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing an array doesn't initialize the elements of the array.  To go this route you need to do this:

```
hp[i] = new HorizontalPanel();
```

Comment: That being said, you can just add the labels to the vertical panel if you like, removing the need for the HorizontalPanel array.